# R shiny: Retrieve home directory of a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

Is there a function or a way to retrieve the path of root home directory of a shiny app?

The shiny app I run creates multiple directories and changes working directory. But at point in the app, I need to jump to the home directory. `getwd()` won't work unless I run it first and save it as a variable or something.

I am thinking of something like the below command used to read a file from a package home directory on any platform without knowing the actual path.

```
#get root dir
system.file()
# read a file from the root dir of a package
a <- system.file("bla",package="foo")
```

The approach has to work locally, on shiny-server and shinyapps.io. (In situations where I cannot set the path manually).

Comment: What's wrong in "running it first and saving it as a variable or something"?

Comment: I think the first working directory is always the one with the source code, right? Just grab that as the first thing you do, like nicola implies?

Comment: How should R/shiny remember where it started? It's rendered as something and it's not like server.R and ui.R are directly displayed. Your best and maybe only option is what @nicola said ;)

Comment: If it actually works, the answer to the question should be that saving the result of getwd() at the start should provide the path to the app directory. That answer is not self-evident from the question or comments.